# Vitest throws an Error: Element type is invalid when testing a react component that isn't exported as default

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, vitest

I'm trying to write a unit test with Vitest for my routing component.

It works when I have my Home Component in separate file exported with default and imported without {}. But when I try to test it from within another file it throws this error

`Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

RoutingComponent.tsx

```
import { useRoutes } from "react-router-dom";
import { getRoutes } from "./Routing.Service";

export default function RoutingComponent() {
  const routes = getRoutes();
  return useRoutes([...routes]);
}

export function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <p>Home</p>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

getRoutes inside Routing.Service.tsx

```
import routes from "./Routes.Config";

export const getRoutes = () => {
  const returnedRoutes = routes
    .map(route => {
      if (route.component) {
        return { path: route.path, element: route.component };
      }
    });

  return [...returnedRoutes];
};
```

Routes.Config.tsx

```
import { RouteElement } from "./Routes.Types";
import { Home } from "./RoutingComponent";

const routes: Array<RouteElement> = [
  {
    name: "Home",
    path: "/",
    component: <Home />,
  },
];

export default routes;
```

I have my testing

```
import { MemoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import RoutingComponent from "./RoutingComponent";

describe("Routing Component", () => {
  it("Should route to home on /", () => {
    render(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/"]}>
        <RoutingComponent />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );
    expect(screen.getByText(/home/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Test Pass when
in Routes.Config.tsx I import Home as default
import Home  from "./Home";

But throws the error when it's a regular export/impot

Edit:
I think the problem wasn't having multiple components in the same file the problem was having

```
export default function RoutingComponent() {
  const routes = getRoutes();
  return useRoutes([...routes]);
}
```

In the same file when I moved it to a separate file it worked but idk why

Comment: I think the problem wasn't having multiple components in the same file the problem was having 

```export default function RoutingComponent() {
  const routes = getRoutes();
  return useRoutes([...routes]);
}```

In the same file when I moved it to a separate file it worked but idk why